# What is the simplest way to add a png image to a window in my Java program?

Tags: java, image, class, methods, import

*Background*

I have a class for a graphical representation of a die, and a switch statement where each case accounts for the user inputting a value 1 - 6, each case doing a method to draw respective dots on the die.

** My Question **

I need the default to display text saying something to the extent of "Invalid entry" for 0 or >6, but if I wanted to also display a png image on the die when invalid, how do I go about this?

I am new to Java, so I need to know what methods or classes I may need to import/use to add in a picture, and I'd also like to know **where I should save the image**

I do not have a src folder under my Java Project, it's weird, and I do not have a bin, which I've heard of before. If necessary, I can copy the files into a new, well-setup java project.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Image;


public class PictureBox
{

   public JFrame f = new JFrame();
   public JButton b = new JButton();

   public PictureBox()
   {

      f.setUndecorated(true);
      f.setSize(50, 50);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setLocation((200), (200));


      ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("pic.png");
      Image icon = pic.getImage();
      Image real = icon.getScaledInstance(50, 50, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
      //For the 50's, put in the actual dimensions you want the picture to be
      pic = new ImageIcon(real);

      b.setIcon(pic);

      f.add(b);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setEnabled(false);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

   }

}
```

This will do the plain and simple of setting up an image. I don't know how your program is implemented so edit in whatever way you need it to.

Now as for where the picture goes, depending on the IDE (I use JGrasp), you may just need to toss it in the same folder as the class. This is not organized in the slightest, but it will most likely work for the moment.

Also pic.png is the name my picture is called, enter in the name of your picture